# How do I change a variable outside of a class in C#?

Tags: c#

I am making a very simple multiple choice console game. I have created a finite state machine using enums and if else states all within a while loop (while game = true).

The issue is, inside of the class level.level1 (contains level info) it needs to change myState to the new state which is in the main program, but it can't impact it. Any ideas on how to make this happen? I'm stumped.

```
       var game = true;
        while (game = true)
        {

            State myState = State.intro;
            //first level
            if (myState == State.intro)
            {
                level.Intro();
            }
            else
            {
                if (myState == State.contact1)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Wroked");
                }
```

in the level class:

```
        Console.WriteLine(name + " What are you doing, I need your help!");
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        Console.WriteLine("\nA. Who is this? \nB. How are you doing this?\nC. How do you know my name?");
        var res = Console.ReadLine();
        char response = res[0];
        switch (response)
        {
            case 'a':
                State myState = State.contact1;
                break;
            case 'b':
                Console.WriteLine("\nright");
                break;
            case 'c':
                Console.WriteLine("\nleft");
                break;

        }
```

There's obviously more code than this, but that's the important part. you can see full code here: 
https://gist.github.com/MajorMojo/700936c02f1430de44b4559f0579917d
https://gist.github.com/MajorMojo/5bba21cb977a4b768029e765a0d74886

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you either need to pass a game object into the level class or make some static variables.

I would do the first one and have a GameEngine class that is created by main and maintains the overall state of the game. It can have a SetState method (or State property). Pass the GameEngine object into the level when you create  it.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest starting with a basic intro to programming tutorial. The C# one isn't too bad: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664628(v=vs.71).aspx

You're missing a lot of basic concepts. It would be a lot easier for you to pick them up by working through a complete tutorial than by asking individual questions here.

Comment: I'm currently doing a course and I'm building this to put the things I've learned to use. This one issue isn't something I've had to handle before.